# Is it possible to use packed structs with DPI

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

Suppose I have a packed struct:

```
typedef struct packed {
   logic a;
   logic [7:0] b;
   bit  [7:0] c;
   logic [7:0] [31:0] d;
} my_struct;
```

And I want to pass it into a C function:

```
import "DPI" context function int my_dpi_function (input my_struct data);
```

How do I read values on C side?:

```
int my_dpi_function (void* data) 
{  
    ... ?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes you can use them. At `c` side you just get a stream of bits. You have walk it, using `get` functions from `svdpi.h` to recreate your struct fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type you need is defined in the `svdpi.h` header:

```
svLogicVecVal
```

So, you need something like:

```
int my_dpi_function (svLogicVecVal* data) 
{  
    ... 
    return 0;
}
```

`svLogicVecVal` is itself a struct. It has two fields - `aval` and `bval` (or sometimes, eg in Cadence, `a` and `b`). From `svdpi.h`:

> ```
> typedef struct t_vpi_vecval {
> #ifdef P1800_2005_VECVAL
>     uint32_t a;
>     uint32_t b;
> #else
>     uint32_t aval;
>     uint32_t bval;
> #endif
> } s_vpi_vecval, *p_vpi_vecval;
> #endif
>
> /* (a chunk of) packed logic array */
> typedef s_vpi_vecval svLogicVecVal;
> ```

The `aval` and `bval` fields are encoded thus (the so-called "canonical representation"):

```
bval aval | 4-state verilog value
----------|----------------------
  0    0  |   0
  0    1  |   1
  1    0  |   X
  1    1  |   Z
```

So, you can access the `aval` and `bval` fields in your C. It turns out that for vectors wider than 32-bits, the most-significant 32-bit word is at the highest pointer address.

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2k33

**SV**

```
module test;

  typedef struct packed {
    logic a;
    logic [7:0] b;
    bit  [7:0] c;
    logic [7:0] [31:0] d;
  } my_struct;

  import "DPI-C" context function int my_dpi_function (logic [272:0] data);

  initial
    begin
      automatic my_struct data = '{1'b0,8'hAA,8'h55,256'h0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF};
      $display("%h",data);
      my_dpi_function (data);
    end

endmodule
```

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <svdpi.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int my_dpi_function (svLogicVecVal* data) {
    data+=8;
    cout << "# C++: ";
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
      cout << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << (data--)->aval;
    cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong.  X is encoded as 11.   You seem to have X and Z reversed.